# react-native-maps stopped app in android

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I'm trying to add `react-native-maps` in my react-native. but when I add this library & link to my app then I'll run-android that successfully run that app but when app completely render it will be stopped. So anyone please suggest me how to solve that problem.

```
dependencies {
compile (project(':react-native-maps')){
  exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
compile project(':react-native-background-job')
compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.2'
}
```

Comment: I don't know the exact cause of the issue but looks like you have not set up it properly in Android. For example, you have not included the `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.2`.  Please go through the set up guide again https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md

Comment: thank It's working @Ravi Raj